# Flutter gradient issues

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, linear-gradients

[Flutter gradient issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAMXz.png)

When I place a specific color I have problems with the gradient, but when I place a default color, for example Colors.blue, then it is solved, also when I remove opacity from the colors, that's why the two colors below do not have that problem.
The problem is that I have to use the colors that the designer gives me.

```
body: Container(
      // height: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            stops: [0.0, 0.54, 1.0],

              colors: [
                Color(0xFF00092B),
                Color(0xE0001D5E),
                Color(0xC722004D),
              ],
              // tileMode: TileMode.clamp
          )
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: I could not understand what is the problem and what you are trying to achieve ..

Comment: @ReginaldoCosta, Sorry, my English is not very good so I can hardly explain the problem. I want to have a three-color gradient, the two light colors of the gradient look good, but the dark color looks bad. In the image I put it is better understood. But a user already told me that dartpad doesn't look bad, so it could be my computer or the AVD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gradient looks fine using DartPad: https://www.dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b?

It's probably your emulator screen playing up.

Comment: You're right! Thank you very much for your answer, it was very useful.